# Errno22 in merger.write

Tags: python, pypdf

```
merging pdf pages...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\downloader.py", line 262, in <module>
    merger.write(f"{book_title}.pdf")
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_merger.py", line 344, in write
    my_file, ret_fileobj = self.output.write(fileobj)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_writer.py", line 932, in write
    stream = FileIO(stream, "wb")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'The syntax of serial verbs in Gojri.pdf'
```

I tried to capture multiple webpages and merge them, but something went wrong as shown above. So How can I fix that problem?

Comment: please post the code:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As the documentation states, `merger.write` expects to receive a file handle, NOT a file name string.  Use `open` first.  https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/merging-pdfs.html